# Express routes and middleware with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: express, routes, google-cloud-functions, middleware

### Question

How do I use Express within Firebase Cloud Functions?

### Expectations

Using either of the URLs I've setup, I expect to see, `"Hello from Express on Firebase!"` in the console logs.

Why? My understanding is, `"*"` means all routes requested should `response.send("Hello from Express on Firebase!");`

```
app.get("*", (_request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Express on Firebase!");
});
```

### Issue

When I use, `https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld` I get the expected `Hello from Firebase!` in the logs. Should I also see `"Hello from Express on Firebase!"`?

When I use, `https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/api`, I get a `404 error`

> The URL, `https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/api` is the issue. See why in the answer below.

### Code

```
// Express
import express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors")({
  origin: "*"
});
app.use("*", cors);

// Firebase Functions SDK
import functions = require("firebase-functions");

app.get("*", (_request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Express on Firebase!");
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((_request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

### tl;dr

An example of what I'm hoping to accomplish is [here](https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-86ed26f9144c), but none of the code examples worked for me. I get I get a `404 error` with each one.

The Express Documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) shows a similar HelloWorld example, but I confuse how Firebase takes the place of `app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))`

Is `cors` working properly in my example code? Although I get the expected response and log, Chrome console warns: `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://appengine.google.com/_ah/lo....`

I have a Slack App that is hitting these URLs (I hit them with chrome too). Eventually, I'd like to use Botkit middleware in my Google Cloud Functions. I don't yet grasp proper setup of Express `app.use()` and `app.get()`

Comment: I'm seeing the use of `firebase.json` with `hosting` parameters. My example project isn't using hosting, and I don't _think_ it needs to. The example in this [Firebase Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&feature=youtu.be) is similar but different enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

I made a simple mistake by treating `/api` as a function when it's actually a part of the path.

By using this URL with the trailing `/`

`https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/api/`

I'm now hitting the Express route and function.